решение задачи на любом языке
Ограничение по времени: 2 секунды
Ограничение по памяти: 256 мегабайт
В первой строке вводится четыре числа через пробел: n, a, b, c, где n - кол-во элементов массива, а a, b и c - целые числа.
Во второй строке вводится сам массив через пробел.
К каждому элементу массива можно прибавлять один. Нужно найти, сколько минимально раз нужно к каким либо элементам массива прибавить один, что бы выполнялось условие:
некоторые элементы должны делиться на любой из делителей a, b и c.
К примеру, при вводе 3 5 3 4 (5 3 4 - делители), и массива 9 7 11 нам потребуется прибавить к девятке 1, что-бы этот элемент массива делился на пять, а к 11 прибавить 1, что-бы этот элемент массива делился на 3 и 4. Соответственно, мы два раза прибавили по единице и вывод равен двум.
ещё пример: 1 999999 999998 999997
987654321987654321
вывод: 12339678023345673
любой язык программирования

Дубль
